# Failed to start postgres database

Tags: postgresql, ubuntu-16.04

I tried to restart Postgres database. Then it shows an error.

```
 * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server                                                                                                       
 * The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
   2018-09-04 10:37:05 UTC [2573-1] FATAL:  could not create lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
                                                                                                                                     [fail]
```

More than 4 applications running on this test server. I need a fix for this issue.

Answer (score 1):

With an error message such as:

> *"could not create lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied"*

I imagine the first thing you did was copying that error message and asking the internet for help.

So please step back, relax, and **read  the error message** - it is quite descriptive.

Then find the directory where postgres writes the PID file. (The `external_pid_file =` setting from the postgresql.conf.)
And, maybe, just a random thought,  check the permissions and ownership of that directory and PID file. Those should be such that the postgres user can write there.
If you installed Postgres on a separate block device, check that it is mounted and writeable.

Comment: first I read the error in detail.  This was the first error.                                            * Starting PostgreSQL 9.5 database server                                                                                                * Removed stale pid file.
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output:
2018-09-04 10:53:22 UTC [2323-1] FATAL:  could not remove old lock file "postmaster.pid": Permission denied
2018-09-04 10:53:22 UTC [2323-2] HINT:  The file seems accidentally left over, but it could not be removed. Please remove the file by hand and try again.

Comment: I removed the pid file. then I landed into this error posted in the question.